# ubuntu 14.04 no system preferences in Unity

Tags: unity, keyboard, language-support

No preferences in System settings too. I am looking to change the keyboard to Romanian.
In System settings --> Language Support --> Install/Remove Languages I found and installed Romanian, but in upper right corner only En shows up. In Unity, nothing about Preferences or keyboards. What do I have to do in order to have, next to "En", the "Ro" abbr. for Romanian ?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "En" icon, then select "Text Entry Settings". There you can use the "+" button to add a Romanian keyboard layout.

You don't have to install a language in order to have the necessary keyboard layout.